# How to use jquery .css in a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

OK, this is probably quite easy, but I cannot find it on Google or stackoverflow.

Instead of

```
var color = $(div).css('color')
```

I want to store the css in a variable.

```
var theCss = $(div).css  
var color = theCss('color')  // no, doesn't work
```

Is it at all possible? Of course the reason why I want this is much more complicated, so I would be very much helped if there is somehow a way to store

Comment: Have you checked out this link? [Get all CSS using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element)

Comment: @user2646829 you beat me to it.

Comment: Do you want that `theCss` will always return the actual calculated value of the element or the one the element had at the time you do `var theCss = $(div).css`

Comment: @t.niese Good point. The one it had at that time. That makes a big difference, right? The reason I am asking is because I need to find out which CSS elements change when the mouse goes over a A HREF. Don;t ask why - it is complicated.

Comment: If you want to compare two states you need to cache those values. Comparing all css properties might be a pain and unnecessary, so you should check if it is really necessary to compare all and only cache those (e.g. like shown in the answer of **[Pointy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25747220/1960455)**). But it seems that your use-case is that special that most answers would not be _correct_ as they won't fully address your issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It;s a little bit more complicated than you expect, but you can use `.bind` mixed with `$.fn.css`. Something like this:

```
var cssFunc = $.fn.css.bind($('p'));
```

Then, you can call it like this:

```
cssFunc('color');
```

You can also change the css with this method:

```
cssFunc('color', red);
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/f8yanzsu/

---

**For the browser support,** as @dfsq said, you can use `$.proxy`, the jQuery polyfill of the `.bind()` function, which is supported by IE 9 and upper.

```
var cssFunc = $.proxy($.fn.css, $('p'));
```

---

**Note:** This method works for all jQuery methods, not just css.

Comment: Wow, I would have NEVER found that. Glas I asked here. I hope it works on all browsers, I will test.

Comment: @Roemer It will not work in IE<9. If you need old IE better to go with this: `$.proxy($.fn.css, $('p'))`.

Comment: @dfsq out of curiosity, except for the support, is there an other reason to use use `proxy`?

Comment: No, only support, as I said. Doesn't make sense to use `$proxy` if there is `.bind`.

Comment: Bad thing is, I need to get a COPY of the css, not a link to the original. I need to see what changes are made to the css since I made the copy. So even though the answer = 100% correct, it does not yet provide a solution for me. But with all the help I got here, I will be able to find a second best solution that works. ;)

Comment: @Roemer What do you mean a copy of the css? I so not understand what you try to achieve ahah!

Comment: I want a time based copy of the CSS. I need to know how the CSS is before the mouse goed over the element. Then when the mouse goes over the element, I want to compare the css of the element to the "backup" and see what has changed. My bad, not yours.

PS Don't ask why I want this - it is complicated, but I need it. ;) (I started explaining but it just got too long and complicated.)

Comment: @Roemer if you would take the time to explain why you think you need to do this, somebody might be able to suggest a completely different approach to the larger problem you're facing.

Comment: That's true, from what i understand, you can do what you want with the Chrome console.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get the sum total of all CSS from jQuery. You can however pass in an array of property names (as of jQuery 1.9) and get back a list of values:

```
var cssStuff = $(div).css(["color", "fontSize", "width"]);
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted, out of curiosity? Who downvotes without providing any explantion; what's even the point?